# while posting data to web_service

Tags: php

i am trying to send data to web_service using this link.

> http://localhost/FixItApp/admin.php?serial_number=mmm&items=asd&brand=qwe&price=sd&user_name=vfd

but data is not posting, can't figure_out why.
here is my web_service.

```
<?php

$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "not set";
if(isset($_REQUEST))
    {
        $txt = serialize($_REQUEST); 
    }

fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);

require_once "DatabaseConnection.php";
$result = null;

if ($_GET)
    {
        /* User table attribute */
        $serial = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "serial_number", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $item = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "items", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $item_brand = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "brand", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $item_price = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "price", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $name = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "user_name", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


        if(is_null($serial))
            {
                echo "Null Values";
            }
        else
            {
                $select_ExistUser = @"SELECT serial_number from admin WHERE serial_number = '$serial'";
                $resultUser = selectQuery($select_ExistUser);
                if(count($resultUser)==0)
                    {
                        $query_one = "INSERT INTO admin(serial_number, items, brand, price, user_name)
                                          VALUES('$serial', '$item', '$item_brand', $item_price, '$name')";

                        $result = insertQuery($query_one);

                        $insert_id = $db->insert_id;

                        if($insert_id)
                            {
                                echo "Great";
                            }
                    }
                else
                    {
                        echo "ResultUser > 0";
                    }

            }
    }
if ($result)
    {
        $arr= [
               "result" => $insert_id,
               "status_message" => "Good",
               "status_code" => 1
               ];
    } 
else 
    {
        $arr = [
                "result" => $result,
                "status_message" => "Sorry!",
                "status_code" => -1
                ];
    }
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: What is it doing, and what should it be doing?

Comment: it should have insert data into Sql_table

Comment: What output are you getting? And what does `insertQuery` look like.

Comment: $arr = [
            "result" => $result,
            "status_message" => "Sorry!",
            "status_code" => -1
        ];

Comment: this is the output am getting

Comment: So $result is falsey. Sounds like your SQL query is failing. If this is using mysqli, try looking at [mysqli_error](http://php.net/mysqli_error) and see if you can determine why it's failing.

Comment: i can't figure_out problem i think query is fine

Comment: If you're sure the SQL is correct, then it's not being run. Add some debugging and check that you're actually getting to that bit of code.

Comment: Change `"Sorry!"` to `$db->error` so it shows the reason for the query failure.

Comment: pointing error at the line where i post "$db->error"